# How to Autowired service dynamically

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a interface like BaseService and two Class CoreServiceImpl and TenantServiceImpl both of them extend BaseService. Now I want to Autowired BaseService in My controller, how to run specific service (core/tenant) by passing any param ?

Comment: It will be better if you explain at which point you wanna use which one

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with `@Profile`:

```
@Component
@Profile("core")
public class CoreServiceImpl {}


@Component
@Profile("tenant")
public class TenantServiceImpl {}
```

And then run spring with `--spring.profiles.active=core/tenant`

Comment: Thanks for all of your support